# bltoolkit association with stored procedure execution

Tags: associations, bltoolkit, proc

I have 2 entities:

```
[TableName("is_userrole")]



public class UserRole
  {
      [MapField("id"), PrimaryKey, Identity,
      public Guid id;
      [NotNull]
      public string Name;       
  }    
[TableName("is_users")]
  public class User
  {
      [MapField("id"), PrimaryKey, Identity,
NonUpdatable]
      public Guid Id;
      [NotNull]
      public string Name;
      [NotNull]
      public string Login;
      [NotNull]
      public string Password;

      public Guid UserRole_Id;    
      [Association(ThisKey = "UserRole_Id", OtherKey = "Id",
CanBeNull = false)]
      public UserRole UserRole;
  }
```

and stored procedure on sql server which gets data from query

[Select u.*, r.* from is_users u
   inner join is_userrole r on u.userrole_id = r.id]

if i use linq query like

var query = from u in db.User
                              select new
                              {
                                  u.Id,
                                  u.Login,
                                  u.Password,
                                  u.UserRole_Id,
                                  u.UserRole
                              };

Associations filling, but if I execute procedure only parent object(i.e. user) filled.
How in bltoolkit.net associations with stored procedures made?
Or it can be only manually realised?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I don't have any experience with this but I quickly looked at the unit-tests and it looks like [MapResultSet](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.ExecuteResultSet.ashx?HL=mapresultset) could help you

the unit test are here ->  UnitTests\CS\Mapping\ResultSetTest.cs

Comment: I have SP - SelectByLogin(string) and 

    public abstract class UserAccessor : gosDBAccessor<User>
        {
            public abstract User SelectByLogin(string @login);            
        }

This SP has complex query with INNER JOIN in it.
Execution - 
    UserAccessor ua = DataAccessor.CreateInstance<UserAccessor>();
       User user = ua.SelectByLogin(Login);
This user doesn't have UserRole property filled.
Where is the place for mapset include in code?

Comment: Really don't understand your question here, did you take a look at the unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

`AssosiationAttribute` is used only for Linq expressions.

Point to know: BLT does NO "hidden" actions, for ex. if you will change your linq code as: `db.User.ToList()` you'll see that UserProperty is not filled. In your sample filling is done because you have said to done it in select clausue, and `Association` is used only to build proper 'INNER JOIN' in SQL.